# Failed to create provisioning profile, "personel team" keyword lost

Tags: xcode

[image]

personel team" lost. and not working

failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Select a device run destination to have Xcode register it.

how to fix this ı spend 2 day..

Comment: Quang Hà :( hope someone can help us